# 15 points for answer being accepted not synced until next upvote

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

I've seen quite a few questions about rep not being synced across various accounts, but haven't found one that covered the specific bug I think I've found.

One of my answers was accepted and the reputation on that account increased by 15 points as expected. However, my profiles on my other accounts still showed the reputation for this account without the additional 15 points for being accepted (though the upvote points and those for a bounty were added).

This 15 point difference continued for nearly 2 weeks, during which time I did not answer any more questions on the account in question. Yesterday, I did post an answer on that account, and after it was upvoted, the profiles on my other accounts were correctly updated with the upvote points plus the "missing 15".

Could it be that there's a bug with having an answer accepted not triggering the cross-site synchronisation (while upvotes/bounties do)?

Comment: you have multiple accounts ?

Comment: @Lucifer: My question/bug report wouldn't make much sense if I didn't ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this was on your Programmers.SE account for [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141988/practical-considerations-for-html-css-naming-conventions-syntax/142703#142703)?

Stack Exchange (the source of those [accounts snapshots](https://stackexchange.com/users/958617/aaamos?tab=accounts)) is informed of all reputation events through a Redis list, which it processes as those events occur.

It's possible that an event was incorrectly handled, especially with the bounty and accept happening so close together, as some events have different priorities.

Any discrepancies are usually fixed very quickly, because a new reputation event carries the user's current rep score - in your case, since no events happened for two weeks, the error persisted.

We'll take a look at the event aggregation code to see if anything is amiss.

Comment: Yep, that's the one - thanks for the detailed response. Just thought I'd point this out as a possible bug, in case someone else encounters the same issue.

Comment: Just to let you know, the exact same thing seems to have happened again. No big deal, I'm sure the 15 accept points will sync through on the next upvote, but if you're trying to fix the bug here's another instance of it (upvote followed by accept within the same minute).

Comment: Looks like [another case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285563/vote-count-in-network-profile-not-updated-even-after-long-time) of this bug is still happening?