# Vote count in network profile not updated even after long time

Tags: bug, network-profile, deleted-accounts, top-questions

My [question](//buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/17304) had 5 upvotes before a user was removed together with their votes and the question now has a score of 4. Two months have passed but my [network profile](//stackexchange.com/users/9000753) still shows my question as having a score of 5. What is wrong?

PS: I just received another upvote on the question, so now the network profile correctly shows its score of 5.

Comment: As Jarrod explains [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129496/152859), the network profile is synchronized via some list, probably the "user removed" event does not update that list. You need to wait for other reputation event, e.g. another vote on your question, and it will most likely cause your network profile to be updated.

Comment: Which indeed did the trick @sha

Comment: @Pat true, can't mark this as duplicate of the other one though since it's marked as completed. Wonder if we should post answer here to explain what happened?

Comment: Of course. Feel free to add an answer @sha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially the same bug as reported in [15 points for answer being accepted not synced until next upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129491/15-points-for-answer-being-accepted-not-synced-until-next-upvote).

As Jarrod explains [in his answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129496/152859):

> Stack Exchange (the source of those accounts snapshots) is informed of all reputation events through a Redis list, which it processes as those events occur.
>
> ...
>
> Any discrepancies are usually fixed very quickly, because a new reputation event carries the user's current rep score - in your case, **since no events happened for two weeks, the error persisted**

In your case, the "user removed" event was not added to that Redis list, hence the network reputation was not updated. After a "real" reputation event occured (upvote) it was added to the list, and it was all updated as expected.